# PhotoKit: How To Sort Photos Randomly

Tags: swift, nssortdescriptor, photokit

When fetching assets from the user's photo library, you must specify how you want the photos to be sorted. You do this by passing in a `NSSortDescriptor()`. There are a few completions, but I'm wondering if there's any way to pass in a "random sort".

I'm hoping there's something similar to the `.sort` function used like this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3]
arr = arr.sorted { Bool.random() }   // Returns the array, sorted randomly
```

Is there any way I can achieve a "random sort" with `NSSortDescriptor()` ?

If not, is there any way to fetch random photos from a user's library (without fetching all of them and then sorting on those randomly) ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use a comporator in NSSortDescriptor for flexible sorting:

[How to create an NSSortDescriptor using the comparator signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726153/how-to-create-an-nssortdescriptor-using-the-comparator-signature/42726448#42726448)

Comment: This helps, thanks. I can't seem to find a way to use it to sort them randomly, though. Do you know a way?

Comment: I have just checked the operation of the comparator in fetched a photo in photoKit. Comparator not working. I think it doesn't work for photoKit as for Core Data - >
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14938653/unsupported-nssortdescriptor-comparator-blocks-are-not-supported